# Fibrally monic implies monic for flat schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $i_1: X_1 \to Y$ and $i_2: X_2 \to Y$ be two monics maps of schemes flat and locally of finite presentation over $S$.

Assume that for all $s \in S$, the fibral map $i_1(s)$ factorizes through $i_2(s)$: $X_1(s) \to X_2(s) \to Y(s)$. Can we prove that $i_1$ factorizes through $i_2$?

(A map $X_1 \to X_2$ is monic if and only if it is fibrally monic, but the difficulty here is that I don't know yet it exists.)

Comment: What is a monic map?

Comment: A monomorphism, ie a radicial and formally unramified morphism.

Comment: I dont think that this is true with the hypotheses as stated. Fix a field $k$. Let $X_1 = X_2 = S = Spec(k[x]/x^2)$. Let $Y = Spec(k[x,y]/(x^2, y^2)$. Take the $S$-morphism $X_1 \to Y$ given by $y \mapsto 0$. Take the $S$-morphism $X_2 \to Y$ given by $y \mapsto x$. These are both monomorphisms (in fact closed immersions). When you base-change to the unique $S$-fiber, both morphisms are the same. But the closed immersions are not the same by construction ($y$ is in the kernel of the first immersion, but not in the kernel of the second one).

Comment: In the positive direction, I think that the factorization is true if you assume $X_2 \to Y$ to be flat (i.e. an open immersion).

Comment: I believe it is possible to weaken the assumption of flatness of $X_2 \to Y$ under certain assumptions if $S$ is reduced, but that depends on your specific context.